# Qual destes três códigos é o mais recomendado em memória e velocidade?

Tags: php, array, desempenho, memória

Gostaria de saber qual destes códigos seria mais recomendado visando velocidade, visto que os três efetuam o mesmo trabalho:

#### 1

```
$rand_length = 1;
$rand_rules = range(0, 9);
shuffle($rand_rules);
$rand_rules = array_slice($rand_rules, 1, 9);
$uni_id1 = "";
for ($rand_id = 0; $rand_id < $rand_length; $rand_id++) {
    $uni_id1 .= $rand_rules[$rand_id]; }
echo $uni_id1."\n";
```

#### 2

```
$rand_length = 1;
$rand_rules = "123456789";
$uni_id2 = "";
for ($rand_id = 0; $rand_id < $rand_length; $rand_id++) {
    $uni_id2 .= $rand_rules[mt_rand(0, strlen($rand_rules)-1)]; }
echo $uni_id2."\n";
```

#### 3

```
$rand_rules = range(0, 9);
shuffle($rand_rules);
$rand_rules = array_slice($rand_rules, 1, 1);
$uni_id3 = implode($rand_rules, "");
echo $uni_id3."\n";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sua pergunta é muito interessante. O php como qualquer linguagem de programação requer optimizações no ciclo de desenvolvimento em qualquer projecto. Quanto a questão colocada e no meu entender a sua última opção deverá ser a mais ágil.

O php é uma linguagem de script desenvolvida em C. A rapidez irá depender sempre de muitos factores, mas sem dúvida que a sua terceira opção entrega ao C o trabalho "sujo" de ciclos que em C vai certamente ser mais rápido, no entanto a mesma tarefa é realizada com o recurso a mais do que uma função, o que me deixa dúvidas.

Assim, a única forma de você saber qual será a mais rápida é utilizar um **timer**... no fim terá uma ideia muito perto da realidade.

Comment: você poderia me mostrar um exemplo de timer? achei um muito complexo mas não parece funcionar pois mostra exatamente a mesma coisa

Comment: antes: $time_start = microtime(true); depois do método: $time_end = microtime(true); e por fim: $execution_time = $time_end - $time_start.... dará concerteza um ideia

Answer (score 12):

Tem pouca diferença e em PHP a preocupação não deve ser essa. Isso é chamado de micro-otimização e deve ser evitada até que ela se mostre absolutamente necessária. Se você precisasse mesmo otimizar memória e velocidade a primeira coisa que eu te diria é trocar de linguagem. PHP não é adequada para aplicações que exigem a melhor otimização.

Em PHP otimizações razoáveis são aqueles em que você escolhe a estrutura de dados e o algoritmo correto. Não melhorar pequenos detalhes de código.

Dito isto a segunda parece ser ligeiramente melhor em performance e talvez minimamente em memória (de novo, reforço que não faz diferença real). Me parece ser mais legível também (nem todo mundo concordaria). Esta sim é uma boa preocupação.

A terceira (que veio depois em edição) parece ser a mais lenta (não posso garantir e nem perderei tempo tentando descobrir, simplesmente não vale a pena) mas pode não ser. É a mais curta e mais simples, mais abstrata. Eu provavelmente iria nela depois que eu já aprendi usar bem o laço. Talvez trocando o `range` pela *string* literal da segunda.

Se você não consegue notar diferença entre elas é porque não faz diferença. E se você medir e ver que uma é melhor que outra, basta mudar um pouco e o resultado pode ser outro. São muitas variáveis influenciando o desempenho tornando difícil fazer uma avaliação definitiva.

---

Dê nomes das variáveis significativos. Você tentou dar bons nomes mas não acertou o alvo. Usar `rand_id` como variável para contar o laço gera confusão porque ela indica que deveria ser alguma coisa randômica. Me parece que todos esse prefixos `rand` nos nomes estão todos exagerados porque nenhum deles guarda coisas randômicas. Mas é só um parecer. Não sei qual sua real intenção.

Também evite manter a chave final do laço na última linha. Fica mais fácil identificar o fim quando ela está em uma linha sozinha. É gosto mas isso é algo que poucos programadores discordam.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: gostei bastante de sua explicação @bigown sobre o nome das variaveis, estes não são definitivos, criei a esmo, por isso me preocupei em qual dos três utilizar, para poder melhorar aquele que seria o mais recomendável, no caso, para uma aplicação ligeiramente grande com muitas requisições ao banco de dados e geração de muitos núemros aleatórios por muitos usuários ao mesmo tempo, você utilizaria a segunda opção?

Comment: Acho que usaria a terceira. Ainda mais se envolve bando de dados. Banco de dados é tão mais lento que o processamento deste código que ele fará menos diferença ainda. O PHP é lento, não adianta ficar otimizando seu código. Nem o Facebook ficar fazendo micro-otimização no código PHP deles (eles fizeram algo bem mais radical :) )